# Active Directory Implementation in Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I want to perform Active Directory authenticaitons in java where username and password are enetered via login screen .
We have a root directory which has many subdirectories inside. How to perform the authentication so that user gets searched in the whole hierarchy and perform the LDAP binding.
How can it be automated for a user to be looked in all subdirectory inside root ?

Please find the code snippet below :

```
  Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
                  ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                  //ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://127.0.0.1:10389");
                  ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  prop.getProperty("ldapServer"));
                  ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                  ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn="+userName+",ou=Users,ou=ACN,ou=Peterborough,dc=xyz,dc=com");
                  //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");                
                  ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,password);
                  ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
```

The problem I am encountering is that as Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL is hard coded, so searching happens only in this hardcoded directory which does not meet my requirement.

Comment: This isn't AD auth. This is a stupid bind. AD auth is Kerberos.

Answer (score 2):

Most implementation I've seen, use a read only Active Directory to search for the context of the user, then try to login using the full context of the user, and the supplied password.  Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172831/how-do-a-ldap-search-authenticate-against-this-ldap-in-java) will help you get started in the searching part.