# Java: How can I use JNA to perform an ldap search?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jna

I'm doing a POC to see if it's possible to leverage native Windows APIs through JNA to perform ldap search and query for users and other "objects". I know that LDAP programming is best done in .NET, but given my familiarity with Java, I wanted to explore JNA.

I've looked at [advapi32](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.html) but that seems to have support only for authentication and not general ldap queries.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this with JNA? Java does support LDAP.

Comment: The idea is to develop this as a service running on Windows platform. I've seen JNDI code but that looks like a lot of boilerplate code. The auth via JNA is much more straightforward. I wanted to do something similar for ldap search too.

Comment: [18 lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175525/1759845) don't seem "a lot of boilerplate code" to me.

Comment: I mean I would also do it in java but if you got some windows DLL then you should be able to access it...